# Average total duration per day in Excel Pivot table with subtotals

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I've got data for duration of calls for a number of days. I've created a Pivot table that groups dates by week number and right now shows subtotal SUM OF DURATION, i.e. the total time for the whole week.

However, I would like the weekly subtotal to show the average daily duration (e.g. day 1 - 3h, day 2 - 5h, average - 4h).

[image]

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Pivot Table, Goto Values / Value Field Settings and then choose Average instead of Sum.

Comment: The trouble is, the original data is broken by people per day; using average like this, results in average per person, not total per day. :(